# Android tcp connection from client

Tags: android, tcp, connection, tcpclient

I'm trying to make my android phone a client to a server I wrote in python. The server works good (I have tried it) but I can't seem to connect the phone with the server.
This is the function that should create the connection:

```
public String createConnection() throws IOException{
    InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(ipString);
    clientSocket = new Socket(serverAddr, portNumber);
    DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
    BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
    outToServer.writeBytes(Client.INIT_HEY.name());
    String ans = inFromServer.readLine();
    return ans;
}
```

ipString is the server ip received by the user, portNumber is the port number and they are both correct.
When I try to connect to the server, I receive "null" as the error message.

Any thoughts?
Thanks!

Comment: Did you include Internet permissions in the manifest?  I could also recommend using Volley. A good intro: http://arnab.ch/blog/2013/08/asynchronous-http-requests-in-android-using-volley/

Answer (score 0):

Try it over wifi.
If you can find the phone's IP address, try ping it from your dev system.

If your are on cell network, try access web site from browser, make sure the network connection is working.

Answer (score 0):

The error was because I was running a tcp connection on the main thread.. I could've fixed it by making the class an AsyncTask but I prefered adding this:

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

Thanks all!